# How can I import Create Table Statement from SQL Developer into Visio to create an Entity Relationship Diagram?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, visio

I have the following Create table statement from SQL Developer and I am trying to generate an ERD Diagram using 2003 Visio. I was wondering what I need to do to convert the Create Table from SQL Developer to an ERD Diagram Using Visio.

```
CREATE TABLE “TT_TEAM”.”HR_REVOKED_SECURITY_ORGS”
(
“ID” NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
“ACAT_CODE” VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
“APPR_SEQ_NO” NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
“USER_ID” VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
“ACTION_IND” VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
“ACTIVITY_DATE” DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
“COAS_CODE” VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
“ORGN_CODE” VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
“POSN” VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
“MANDATORY_APPR_IND” VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
“APPR_POSN” VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
“ORGN_MANAGER” VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in Visio. However, you can reverse engineer a database using Visio. The answer to the question below should help you.

[How can I import the contents of an Oracle database into Visio to create an Entity Relationship Diagram?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/how-can-i-import-the-contents-of-an-oracle-database-into-visio-to-create-an-enti)

Comment: You can always run the DDL into a "throw away" schema and reverse engineer from there :-)